# Why is trait not in scope?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and I have made a trait "Shape" and a subclass "Circle" defined within a module "figures". My question is, do I really have to supply a use declaration of Shape inside main with a full path to Shape.rs? If I remove it I get a compilation error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `draw` found for type `figures::circle::Circle` in the current scope                 
 --> src/main.rs:8:7
  |
8 |     c.draw()
  |       ^^^^
  | 
 ::: src/figures/circle.rs:3:1
  |
3 | pub struct Circle {}
  | ----------------- method `draw` not found for this
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
  |
1 | use figures::shape::Shape;
  |

error: aborting due to previous error
```

File structure

```
src/
├── figures
│   ├── circle.rs
│   ├── mod.rs
│   └── shape.rs
└── main.rs
```

--- main.rc ---

```
mod figures;                                                                                                       

// Why is this needed when Shape is exported and redeclared in mod.rs?                                                                                             
use figures::shape::Shape;                                                                                         

fn main() {                                                                                                        
    let c = figures::Circle::new();                                                                                
    c.draw()                                                                                                       
}
```

--- figures/circle.rs ---

```
use figures::shape::Shape;                                                                                         

pub struct Circle {}                                                                                               

impl Circle {                                                                                                      
    pub fn new() -> Circle {                                                                                       
        println!("Circle new");                                                                                    

        Circle {}                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                  

impl Shape for Circle {                                                                                            
    fn draw(&self) {                                                                                               
        println!("Circle draw")                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                  

impl Drop for Circle {                                                                                             
    fn drop(&mut self) {                                                                                           
        println!("Circle drop");                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                              
}
```

--- mod.rs ---

```
// Expose modules to caller                                                                                        
pub mod circle;                                                                                                    
pub mod shape;                                                                                                     

// Redeclare circle::Circle -> Circle and shape::Shape -> Shape                                                    
pub use self::circle::Circle;                                                                                      
pub use self::shape::Shape;
```

--- circle.rs ---

```
pub trait Shape {                                                                                                  
    fn draw(&self);                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I still don't understand why the exposure and redeclaration in mod.rs is not enough. Could someone please explain?

Comment: I turned out that I could use 

mod figures;             
                                                                                  
use figures::Shape;

                                                                                    
fn main() {                                                             

    let c = figures::Circle::new();                                                                                

    c.draw()                                                                                                       

}